# Making input buttons act like <a>'s without JavaScript

Tags: html, css, button, input

I know that I can assign an *onclick* action to `<input type="button"`-style buttons. But is it possible to let it behave like an `<a>` without using JavaScript? I ask because I'm in a situation where technically I'm better off using `<a>`'s, but buttons look nicer.

Comment: Why not use an `<a>` directly? You could style it as a button.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could just use CSS to make your links look like buttons.

For example: [How to make sexy buttons with CSS](http://www.oscaralexander.com/tutorials/how-to-make-sexy-buttons-with-css.html)

Answer (score 3):

While styling with CSS as Justin suggests is probably the better approach, the literal answer to your question is:

```
<form action="where-you-want-to-go.html">
    <input type="submit" value="Hello">
</form>
```

Comment: Also, set method="GET" to be sure you actually send your request as GET and not as POST.

Comment: +1 for providing the literal answer to my question. But since this workaround is rather clumsy, I think I'm better off using button-like `<a>`'s.

Comment: @Pim — GET is the default, there is no need to set it explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

Some CSS libraries such as [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html#buttons) make this very easy.

There is an example (named "One class, multiple tags" quoted below) where you can apply a `.btn` class to `<a>`, `<button>` and `<input>` tags.

```
<a class="btn" href="somelink">Link</a>
<button class="btn" type="submit">Button</button>
<input class="btn" type="button" value="Input">
<input class="btn" type="submit" value="Submit">
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use css to design your links as buttons.
You could use bootstrap , pure or other frontend frameworks you are familiar with because they are more easy to use and you just have to tag their class to an html object to inherit its css designs.